# what's the best practice for setting up multiple mocha tests with one app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to set up a test environment using chai and mocha, along with Appium.  What's the best practice for running multiple mocha tests in a chain?  if I wanted to run all of the tests for my app, how would I go about doing this?  All of the tutorials I've found only show how to add one or two tests and use them separately.

to clarify: I want to run the tests one after another, not all at once.

Comment: found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229424/how-to-set-execution-order-of-mocha-test-cases-in-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows and I keep all my application specific code inside server folder, and below is the script i use to run all my test files at once

```
"test": "SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" && mocha server/**/*.test.js",
"testWatch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
```

****/*.test.js** This Gets all my test files ending with .test.js (a naming convention i like to use).
Though i haven't used chai and appium, but i think i answered your question.

Comment: thanks, I'm looking for a way to run the test files one after another though, not all at once.

Comment: The above syntax will run all test files automatically one-by-one.

Comment: sounds good, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this lately (probably due to my lack of experience with node.js), but eventually I got it working.

It's even set up in BitBucket CI, in such a way that the tests are automatically performed when I make a PR. Unfortunately the repository is private, or I would send you a link.

Anyway, in package.json, I got this:

```
{ 
  "name": "MyProject",
  ...
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -u bdd test"
  }
```

With the proper dependencies of course. `-u bdd` is just to set the user interface/api style.

The `test` subfolder of the project contains a bunch of JavaScript files named `test-whatever.js` each with a `describe` of a test suite. When I run `npm test`, this config will scrape the directory and run the tests in each of the files.

I can't find where I found this solution, though. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753288/how-to-specify-test-directory-for-mocha), but this answer isn't in there. Also [Mocha's website](https://mochajs.org/) suggests that `test` is actually a list of files, so maybe Mocha is just smart at finding files when you specify a part of the file name, a directory name, or a mask with wildcards.